# Spring Security causing PageNotFound

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have struggled a couple days with a problem that happens when I integrate Spring Security on my Spring MVC web application. On the client's side I have some JavaScript code, it generates a post request with a given url which is then mapped to a specific controller on the server's side in order to execute the appropriate code. I get the following error instead:

*"org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/403] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'"*

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I add the following to my web.xml to activate Spring Security:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
      /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/assign/saveAssignment",
        data: {
            "taskID": taskID,
            "userID": userID,
            "isAssigned": !isActive
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            console.log("Saved assignment.");
        }

    })
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/assign/saveAssignment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpHeaders saveAssignment(@RequestParam String taskID, @RequestParam String userID, @RequestParam String isAssigned) {
...
}
```

Servlet definition (within web.xml)

```
...
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first understood that the csrf protection was disabled by default, so all I did to test if csrf protection was blocking my requests was to remove `<csrf/>` from my code.

However, it seems the default behavior is  actually csrf-enabled. After trying many things I finally noticed that the tag csrf can be indeed [configured](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure). So `<csrf disabled="true"/>` disabled it effectively and made my application work fine with spring security. Of course the best will be to re-enable it and add a token to each request.